# Sum of elements in the lists

Tags: python, list, sum, element

I have data from csv look like that:

```
ID, DATE, mm

251691,01/01/2016,16.6
251691,02/01/2016,4.4
251691,08/01/2016,3.7
120530,07/01/2019,55.5
120530,22/04/2019,1.8
```

I want to sum all the "mm" per year and ID

**The result I'm trying to get is something like that:**

```
('251691', '2016')  :  (sum_of_mm_for_each_station_in_that_year, number_of_total_rain_days)
```

That it:

```
('251691', '2016')  :  (24.7, 3)
```

**This is my code:**

```
answer = {}
with open(filename) as f:
        header = line_to_list(f.readline())
        if header[0] != 'ID':
            raise Exception("Bad")
        for line in f.readlines():
            row = line_to_list(line)
            date = row[1]
            mm = row[2]
            year = date [-4:]
            answer[row[0],year] = (mm, date)
```

**the function line_to_list:**

```
def line_to_list(line):
    ''' converts a csv line (string) to a list of items '''
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    return [s for s in line.split(',')]
```

I can not sum the elements.
I thought to group each year by ID and sum the element, but I can't use any module like pandas and etc.

can some one help me with that?
Thank you!

Comment: What's the purpose of `line_to_list` function? If that is a custom function, it'd be better to add that function too.

Comment: Hey, I added the function. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in the code to accommodate your changes :-

```
answer = {}
def line_to_list(line):
    ''' converts a csv line (string) to a list of items '''
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    return [s for s in line.split(',')]
with open("file.txt") as f:
    header = line_to_list(f.readline())
    if header[0] != 'ID':
        raise Exception("Bad")
    for line in f.readlines():
        row = line_to_list(line)
        date = row[1]
        mm = float(row[2])
        year = date [-4:]
        count = 1
        if (row[0], year) in answer:
            mm += answer[(row[0],year)][0]
            count += answer[(row[0],year)][1]
        answer[(row[0],year)] = (mm, count)
print(answer)
```

Result:-

```
{('251691', '2016'): (24.7, 3), ('120530', '2019'): (57.3, 2)}
```

Explanation:-

As the list is mutable and hashable, we can't directly use it to refer to it as a key for a dictionary because a key needs to be hashed. So I explicitly converted it to tuple and then used it.

The part of code `if (row[0], year) in answer:` will check if the tuple is already present in the dictionary and if present it will append its value and increase the count with the lines `mm += answer[(row[0],year)][0]` and `count += answer[(row[0],year)][1]`. I think the other part of the code is clear.

Comment: nps at all, reach out to me for any help . Will be happy to help :)